# JSON Parsing Swift 4

Tags: json, swift, swift4

I was trying to parse some JSON data but had some trouble. Here is the JSON:

```
    {
  "result": {
    "artist": {
      "name": "The Beatles"
    },
    "track": {
      "name": "Yesterday",
      "text": "[Verse 1]\nYesterday\nAll my troubles seemed so far away\nNow it looks as though they're here to stay\nOh, I believe in yesterday\n\n[Verse 2]\nSuddenly\nI'm not half the man I used to be\nThere's a shadow hanging over me\nOh, yesterday came suddenly\n\n[Chorus]\nWhy she had to go\nI don't know, she wouldn't say\nI said something wrong\nNow I long for yesterday\n\n[Verse 3]\nYesterday\nLove was such an easy game to play\nNow I need a place to hide away\nOh, I believe in yesterday\n\n[Chorus]\nWhy she had to go\nI don't know, she wouldn't say\nI said something wrong\nNow I long for yesterday\n\n[Verse 4]\nYesterday\nLove was such an easy game to play\nNow I need a place to hide away\nOh, I believe in yesterday",
      "lang": {
        "code": "en",
        "name": "English"
      }
    },
    "copyright": {
      "notice": "Yesterday lyrics are property and copyright of their owners. Commercial use is not allowed.",
      "artist": "Copyright The Beatles",
      "text": "All lyrics provided for educational purposes and personal use only."
    },
    "probability": "75.00",
    "similarity": 1
  }
}
```

And here is my code so far:

```
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://orion.apiseeds.com/api/music/lyric/Beatles\Yesterday?apikey=xxx") else { return }

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in

            if error != nil {

                print(error!)
            }

            guard let data = data else { return }
            do {

                let data = try JSONDecoder().decode(Result.self, from: data)
                print(data)
            } catch let jsonError {

                print(jsonError)
            }
        }.resume()

struct Result: Codable {

    let artist: [Artist]
}

struct Artist: Codable {

    let name: String
}
```

The error that I get when I try to run it is:

> keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "artist", intValue: nil),
>   Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "No
>   value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"artist\",
>   intValue: nil) (\"artist\").", underlyingError: nil))

All I would like to do is get the lyrics from the song.
Please could someone look at this as I am struggling quite a lot.

Comment: "artist" in a *Result* is not an array, but an object. Change Result to have *let artist: Artist*

Comment: I just tried. Here is the error:keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "artist", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"artist\", intValue: nil) (\"artist\").", underlyingError: nil))

Comment: Also "result" is not top level. You should have some *Codable* that wraps result, as it is in the json:
```struct ResultResponse: Codable {
    let result: Result
}```

Comment: Please most that as an answer as it works!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a proper struct for your model if something comes with a nil, make it optional otherwise it will crash, to convert **JSON** to **Objects** you can use this online tool for the future, is quite **useful**! https://app.quicktype.io/

```
struct AudioSearch: Codable {
    let result: Result
}

struct Result: Codable {
    let artist: Artist
    let track: Track
    let copyright: Copyright
    let probability: String
    let similarity: Int
}

struct Artist: Codable {
    let name: String
}

struct Copyright: Codable {
    let notice, artist, text: String
}

struct Track: Codable {
    let name, text: String
    let lang: Lang
}

struct Lang: Codable {
    let code, name: String
}
```

And use the decode like this:

```
let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(AudioSearch.self, from: data)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should create struct like below for your JSON,

```
struct ResultResponse: Codable {
    let result: Result
}

struct Result: Codable {
    let artist: Artist
    let track: Track
    let copyright: Copyright

    let probability: String
    let similarity: Int
}

struct Artist: Codable {
    let name : String
}

struct Track: Codable {
    let lang: Language

    let name: String
    let text: String
}

struct Language: Codable {
    let code: String
    let name: String
}

struct Copyright: Codable {
    let notice:String
    let artist: String
    let text: String
}
```

Parse it like below,

```
let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(ResultResponse.self, from: data)
```

Whenever you have any doubt creating **JSON Codable**, You can create **Codable** from [json4swift](http://www.json4swift.com/). Paste your valid JSON String and it will create **Codable** objects for you.

[app.quicktype.io](https://app.quicktype.io/) is nice solution to create Codable for your JSON.