# Parse a JSON with swiftyJson

Tags: json, swift, swifty-json

I'm using SwiftyJson and I wrote the code below,

```
for (_, value) in json["assets"] {
   print(value)
}
```

I got this result in my console what is I expect:

```
[
  {
    "urlImage" : "https:myFirstUrl",
    "page" : 1
  },
  {
    "urlImage" : "https:mySecondUrl",
    "page" : 2
  }]
```

But now I want to retrieve "urlImage" to assign this value in a constant.

Comment: Why don't you use Codable? easy example here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50562785/json-parsing-swift-4/50563538#50563538

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
    for (_, value) in json["assets"] {
        for item in value.arrayValue {
            let url = item["urlImage"].stringValue
            print(url)
        }
    }
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Work for me! Thanks