# Parsing JSON file using Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, xcode, parsing

Here is the general structure of a team from our `JSON` file:

```
{"Team11":{
   "results":{
      "leg1":[
         {"g":"m","n":"Name1"}
       ],"leg2":[
         {"g":"m","n":"Name2"}
       ],"leg3":[
         {"g":"m","n":"Name3"}
       ],"leg4":[
         {"g":"m","n":"Name4"}
       ],"leg5":[
         {"g":"m","n":"Name5"}
       ],"leg6":[
         {"g":"m","n":"Name6"}
       ],"leg7":[
         {"g":"m","n":"Name7"},{"g":"m","n":"Name8"}
       ]
  },"tn":"TeamName",
  "division":"co"
} 
}
```

So far we are able to parse up into results categories leg1, leg2, etc. Accessing the info contained in the bracket arrays has not worked so far.

My current idea on why it is failing is because we are storing the `JSON` teams incorrectly via `String:Any`.

My other theory is I just haven't been able to find the correct documentation. Any pointers on where to look or tips would be huge!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please share some code and explain what "has not worked so far". See also [ask].

Comment: I think this old post might help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50562785/json-parsing-swift-4/50563538#50563538

Comment: @AlexL.Rocha Yeah, codable is the right call, good link!

Comment: Please share the code that you have tried and hasn't worked. It may just be the way you are traversing the structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure to add What hasn't worked for you and what you have tried? As a New contributor you need to learn how to post questions. Give it a try with my below answer.

Use `Codable` to parse the `JSON` like below,

```
let welcome = try? newJSONDecoder().decode(Welcome.self, from: jsonData)


// Welcome
struct Welcome: Codable {
    let team11: Team11

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case team11 = "Team11"
    }
}

// Team11
struct Team11: Codable {
    let results: [String: [Result]]
    let tn, division: String
}

// Result
struct Result: Codable {
    let g, n: String
}
```

Note: Your JSON is missing open and ending curly brackets, and I've updated that in your question.

Comment: Codable was the tool I was hoping for, great suggestion!

Comment: @CoolHands: great if that worked. how about upvote and accepting the answer?

Comment: I did both- SO won't display my upvote publicly since my score is too low. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to parse the JSON manually? I'm not sure where you're at with your code, but the standard way to parse a JSON string into an object is this:

```
let jsonData = myJSONString.data(using: .utf8)
```

There is an issue with your JSON though. You can validate a JSON file on [this link](https://jsonlint.com).

Comment: I'll need to include code next time, my fault. I already can access the JSON file and parse through most of it, just couldn't receive certain nested elements, and the JSON above is an excerpt of the trouble area.

Comment: JSON should always come in Data, never in a String.